# Connect to multiple database with GraphQL

Tags: graphql

We are building new GraphQL api using apollo server 2. Most of our data live in MongoDB and we are able to access easily with mongoose. But there are many data points which exists in our mySQL database. How can we connect to multiple database in GraphQL API to connect to mongodb and mySQL ?

Answer (score 2):

Apollo server is not concerned with how many databases you use, so you should be able to setup as many database connections as your node process allows.

You will have to define resolving logic, probably utilizing dataloaders, where some fields are fetching data from the SQL database and some fields fetch data from the mongoDB.

Another strategy you might want to consider is to create separate (micro)services for these databases. Your GraphQL server would then fetch its data from these services, and dropping the database handling altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your layers:

*Client layer (browser) has GraphQL client --> http server layer (Apolo for example) --> GraphQL Server provider, this layer understands GraphQL queries. It holds your GrapgQL resolvers.  --> Data store.*

The place you need to configure your database providers is where the GraphQL Enpoint resides.

I have a Java background, in my case. The setup would have been Javascript client with ability to build GraphQL queries. Http server that is capable of caching the GraphQL query responses. A Jetty server supplied with GraphQL provider.  Then my datasources would have been configured there.

The structure with Node.js is very similar. The layers, the building blocks are the same.